# Why is this indentation wrong?

Tags: haskell

This code gives the following compile error:

```
Error:(17, 1) ghc: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

but if I remove

```
module Main where
```

it works. Since I'm just starting to use Haskell I would like to know why ?

```
module Main where

{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Text.Hamlet (shamlet)
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String (renderHtml)
import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.List (sort)

data Person = Person
    { name :: String
    , age  :: Int
    }

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ renderHtml [shamlet|
<p>Hello, my name is #{name person} and I am #{show $ age person}.
<p>
    Let's do some funny stuff with my name: #
    <b>#{sort $ map toLower (name person)}
<p>Oh, and in 5 years I'll be #{show ((+) 5 (age person))} years old.
|]
  where
    person = Person "Michael" 26
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
```

is supposed to come on the first line in the program, before

```
module Main where
```

These language extensions are supposed to be meta information, external to the program itself (they can also be included as command line options to ghc).

Comment: This. If a `LANGUAGE` pragma is present, it must always be the *first* line of code in the file. (There are probably others, but I can't think of any off-hand.)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: It can follow comments and whitespace-only lines, too; it just has to be the first *meaningful* line.  (So it's not quite as restrictive as a shebang).

Comment: Actually, `LANGUAGE` pragmas and `OPTIONS_GHC` pragmas must occur in a block as the first non-comment non-whitespace thing in the file.  You can of course have more than one such line, and they can't all be first :-)